# Super-tough expectation computation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am working on a paper and am trying to show that the below expectation equals to zero. I suppose computer simulation is the only way to go here? I don't see an easy way to solve this analytically: but I wanted to double check here first.

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{\sigma e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}}{1+2e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}+e^{-\sigma^2t+2\sigma W_t}}\right)\left(1+\frac{e^{-\sigma^2t+2\sigma W_t}-1}{1+2e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}+e^{-\sigma^2t+2\sigma W_t}}\right)\right]$$

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is positive everywhere, so can't have mean zero

Comment: @Empy2: thanks a million!

Comment: Rewriting it more simply, you're trying to evaluate the expectation of

$$ \frac{e^{-0.5\sigma^2 t + \sigma W_t}\big(e^{-0.5\sigma^2 t + \sigma W_t} + \big(e^{-0.5\sigma^2 t + \sigma W_t}\big)^2\big)}{\big(1+e^{-0.5\sigma^2 t + \sigma W_t}\big)^2}$$

right (neglecting a multiplicative factor of $2\sigma$)? There's a common factor there that might make things easier.